# Average length of words in file and removing punctuation python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, loops

I am trying to remove punctuation to calculate the avg numbers of words from a text file. Can someone tell me where i am going wrong please?

```
name = "/Users/Desktop/name.txt"
punct = "!()-[]{};:'\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~"
no_punct = ""
textfile = open(name, "r")
letter_count1 = 0
letter_count2 = 0
for line in textfile:
    for word in line.split():
        for c in word:
            if c not in punct:
                no_punct = no_punct + c
                letter_count1 += 1
                letter_count2 += len(word)   

avg = float(letter_count2)/float(letter_count1)
print("Average words: ", avg)

textfile.close()
```

Comment: How do you know you are "going wrong"? Please [edit] and include a short sample input and output, as well as any errors (if any?) you may be getting.

Comment: Do you want to consider a word avoiding punctuations or discard the whole word, if it contains a punctuation?

Comment: @usr2564301  this is my input hi!! ho?? and my output is 4 however the average should be 2. I would like to remove all punctuation without removing the word

Comment: As I said, please [edit] (<-- link) your question to add all relevant information to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regular expressions to remove anything that's not a word character or white space:

```
import re

num_words = 0
num_chars = 0

with open("/Users/Desktop/name.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        clean = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', line)
        words = clean.split()

        # Operate on list of words...
        num_words += len(words)
        for w in words:
            num_chars += len(w)

    avg = num_chars / num_words
    print("Average word length: {}".format(avg))
```

Comment: I am not allowed use any imports unfortunately. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem of your code was that you've been iterating over every character of every word `for c in word:` to check if it contained unwanted characters from `punct`, so If for example you've been checking word `somewo?rd`, `letter_count1` was incrementing for every character in that word except `?`. You could fix that by checking if any character of `punct` is in our current word without loop using list comprehension.

```
name = "/Users/Desktop/name.txt"
name = 'name.txt'
punct = "!()-[]{};:'\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~"

textfile = open(name, "r")

letter_count1 = 0
letter_count2 = 0
for line in textfile:
    for word in line.split():
        if all(i not in word for i in punct):
            letter_count1 += 1
            letter_count2 += len(word)   

avg = float(letter_count2)/float(letter_count1)
print("Average word length: ", avg)

textfile.close()
```

With input file:

```
test test1
te[]st correct not_wrong
<so_wrong> ~lastone;
```

I got output:

```
Average word length:  5.333333333333333
```

Comment: You can also directly iterate through file pointer without reading using `.read()`. `for line in text file:` as in OPs code is, therefore, not wrong.

Comment: That right, I didn't know you could iterate like that, updating my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, that in your code "letter_count1" should have the number of words, and "letter_count2" the number of chars without the number of the punctuation chars.
Check it:

```
punct = "!()-+[]{};:'\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~"
nwords=letters=0
with open(file_name) as ff:
    for line in ff:
        for w in line.split():
            lth=len(w)-len([1 for c in w if c in punct]) 
            if lth: 
                nwords+=1 
                letters+=lth 

print(letters/nwords)
```